# Do T and T* have the same eigenvalues with the same algebraic multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

I know that  the eigenvalues of T* are the conjugates of T's eigenvalues ,  but how can I see each eigenvalue of T and it's conjugate , the eigenvalue of T*, have the same algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: Do you know $\det(A^*)=\det(A)$?

Comment: Note that $\det(A^*-\lambda I)=\det(A-\lambda^* I)$

Comment: yes you are right I'm editing it, thanks

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I know but can't see how it helps

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the multiplicity of $t-\lambda$ as a factor of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix/operator. What you know about the determinant (I guess it should be $\det(A^*)=(\det(A))^*$) gives you the relation between the characteristic polynomials of $T$ and $T^*$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you tell me please if is it true that if A is similar to B, then A conjugate is similar to B conjugate?

Comment: $A$ similar to $B$, $A=C^{-1}BC$, $\overline{A}=\overline{C^{-1}BC}$ $=\overline{C^{-1}}\overline{B}\overline{C}$ $=\overline{C}^{-1}\overline{B}\overline{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the Schur decomposition:** If $T=QUQ^*$ is the Schur decomposition of $T$, then $T^*=QU^*Q^*$. Since both $U$ and $U^*$ are triangular (upper/lower), their diagonal entries equal to the eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^*$, respectively. Then note that the diagonal entries of $U^*$ are complex conjugate entries of the diagonal of $U$.

**Using the characteristic polynomial**: If $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\det(\lambda I-T)=0$. But since $\det(A)=\overline{\det(A^*)}$, we have that $0=\overline{\det(\lambda I-T)}=\det(\overline{\lambda}I-T^*)$. Hence $\overline{\lambda}$ is the root of $\det(tI-T^*)$, the characteristic polynomial of $T^*$.

You can see that the algebraic multiplicities of eigenvalues of $T$ and the complex conjugate eigenvalues of $T^*$ are equal from both approaches. It is easy to see this from the Schur form. From the characteristic polynomial, it is easy to get this result as well. Note that
$$
p_T(t)=\det(tI-T)=\prod_{i=1}^k(t-\lambda_i)^{\mu_i},
$$
where $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ and $\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are their algebraic multiplicities ($\sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i=n$). Since $p_{T^*}(\overline{t})=\det(\overline{t}I-T^*)=\overline{\det(tI-T)}=\overline{p_T(t)}$ (and thus $p_{T^*}(t)=\overline{p_T(\overline{t})}$), you have that
$$
p_{T^*}(t)=\overline{\prod_{i=1}^k(\overline{t}-\lambda_i)^{\mu_i}}=\prod_{i=1}^k(t-\overline{\lambda_i})^{\mu_i}.
$$

Comment: by using the characteristic polynomial that's what I said, but how do you know about algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: I think I have an idea. Is it true that if A is similar to B, then A conjugate is similar to B conjugate?

Comment: @CnR This can be easily seen from the Schur decomposition. You can also use the Jordan form but it is much harder approach.